# Override product bundle select.phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, phtml, bundled-product

I'm trying to override the select.phtml used on the bundle product view page

I've put it here:

app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

which I think is the correct path based on where the official file is located:

vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

But it doesn't work - anyone know where it SHOULD be placed?

Answer (score 0):

yes,you overrided correctly.

please make sure you are working on correct file. I mean please check in vendor changes reflecting on frontend or not as per your need. if yes then it should also work in your theme.

Make sure you cleared cache after override and given proper permission to file as per your server required.